# How to find an item in array which has the most occurrences

Tags: ruby, arrays

How do I find an item in array which has the most occurrences?

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3].mode
=> 1

['cat', 'dog', 'snake', 'dog'].mode
=> dog
```

Comment: What you're asking about is called the "mode."

Comment: Method "mode" is not working in Rails 4 :(
I found the answer here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921999/ruby-how-to-find-and-return-a-duplicate-value-in-array :)

Comment: @Romans8.38-39 - thanks, thought I was going mad.  Just another useful thing that must be thrown out to break working code, it seems.  Someone needs to fork Rails and put back all the good pieces.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

First build a hash mapping each value in the array to its frequency…

```
arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]

freq = arr.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
#=> {1=>3, 2=>1, 3=>1}
```

… then use the frequency table to find the element with the highest frequency:

```
arr.max_by { |v| freq[v] }
#=> 1
```

Comment: Or may be `freq.max_by { |_, v| v }.first` as the last line.

Comment: if you prefer a on-liner you could also do `arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |v, h| h[v] += 1 }.max_by(&:last)`

Comment: Plenty ways to do this^v^

`to_count = [[5, 6], [1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 8], [1, 2]]`

`counter1 = to_count.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|it, acc| acc[it] += 1}`
`counter2 = Hash.new(0).tap{|h| to_count.each{|it| h[it] += 1}}`
`counter3 = to_count.group_by(&:itself).map{|it, its| [it, its.length]}.to_h`
`counter4 = to_count.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }`

`p counter1.max_by(&:last).first`
`p counter2.max_by(&:last).first`
`p to_count.max_by{|v| counter3[v]}`
`p to_count.max_by{|v| counter4[v]}`

`max1 = to_count.group_by{|n| n}.values.max_by(&:size).first`
`p max1`

Comment: Huh............

Comment: There are lot of way to do it but fastest is to use stack. see https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/8-leader/dominator/

Comment: Isn't this the easiest 'ruby' way to do it? arr.group_by(&:itself).values.max_by(&:size).first

Answer (score 29):

```
array.max_by { |i| array.count(i) }
```

Comment: Instead of providing a code-only answer, adding an explanation on how your answer solves the problem will help your readers to learn.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me! Your code returns the most frequent value only. I've modified it a bit to return all values sorted by max first: array.sort_by { |u| array.count(u) }.reverse

Comment: This is `O(n^2)`, though.

Comment: @YtvwlD optimization wasn't part of the OP's question. If you have a more optimal approach, why not just post it rather than harp on other's answers?

Answer (score 27):

While I adore the grep solution for its elegance and for reminding (or teaching) me about a method in Enumerable that I'd forgotten (or overlooked completely), it's slow, slow, slow. I agree 100% that creating the `Array#mode` method is a good idea, however - this is Ruby, we don't need a library of functions that act on arrays, we can create a mixin that adds the necessary functions *into* the Array class itself.

But the `inject(Hash)` alternative uses a sort, which we also don't really need: we just want the value with the highest occurrence.

Neither of the solutions address the possibility that more than one value may be the mode. Maybe that's not an issue in the problem as stated (can't tell). I think I'd want to know if there was a tie, though, and anyway, I think we can improve a little on the performance.

```
require 'benchmark'

class Array
  def mode1
    sort_by {|i| grep(i).length }.last
  end
  def mode2
    freq = inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
    sort_by { |v| freq[v] }.last    
  end
  def mode3
    freq = inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
    max = freq.values.max                   # we're only interested in the key(s) with the highest frequency
    freq.select { |k, f| f == max }         # extract the keys that have the max frequency
  end
end

arr = Array.new(1_000) { |i| rand(100) }    # something to test with

Benchmark.bm(30) do |r|
  res = {}
  (1..3).each do |i|
    m = "mode#{i}"
    r.report(m) do
      100.times do
        res[m] = arr.send(m).inspect
      end
    end
  end
  res.each { |k, v| puts "%10s = %s" % [k, v] }
end
```

And here's output from a sample run:

```
                                user     system      total        real
mode1                          34.375000   0.000000  34.375000 ( 34.393000)
mode2                           0.359000   0.000000   0.359000 (  0.359000)
mode3                           0.219000   0.000000   0.219000 (  0.219000)
     mode1 = 41
     mode2 = 41
     mode3 = [[41, 17], [80, 17], [72, 17]]
```

The "optimised" mode3 took 60% of the time of the previous record-holder. Note also the multiple highest-frequency entries.

---

A few months down the line, I noticed [Nilesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412169/ruby-how-to-find-item-in-array-which-has-the-most-occurrences/1909239#1909239), which offered this:

```
def mode4
  group_by{|i| i}.max{|x,y| x[1].length <=> y[1].length}[0]
end
```

It doesn't work with 1.8.6 out of the box, because that version doesn't have `Array#group_by`. ActiveSupport has it, for the Rails developers, although it seems about 2-3% slower than `mode3` above. Using the (excellent) [backports](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem, though, produces a 10-12% *gain*, as well as delivering a whole pile of 1.8.7 and 1.9 extras.

The above applies to **1.8.6** only - and mainly only if installed on Windows. Since I have it installed, here's what you get from IronRuby 1.0 (on .NET 4.0):

```
==========================   IronRuby   =====================================
(iterations bumped to **1000**)    user     system      total        real
mode1 (I didn't bother :-))
mode2                           4.265625   0.046875   4.312500 (  4.203151)
mode3                           0.828125   0.000000   0.828125 (  0.781255)
mode4                           1.203125   0.000000   1.203125 (  1.062507)
```

So in the event that performance is super-critical, benchmark the options on your Ruby version and OS. [YMMV](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary).

Answer (score 13):

I found a faster method. Try this:

```
  class Array
    def mode4
      group_by{|i| i}.max{|x,y| x[1].length <=> y[1].length}[0]
    end
  end
```

The Benchmark output:

```
                                    user     system      total        real
mode1                          24.340000   0.070000  24.410000 ( 24.526991)
mode2                           0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (  0.195348)
mode3                           0.120000   0.000000   0.120000 (  0.118200)
mode4                           0.050000   0.010000   0.060000 (  0.056315)
     mode1 = 76
     mode2 = 76
     mode3 = [[76, 18]]
     mode4 = 76
```

Answer (score 11):

```
arr = [ 1, 3, 44, 3 ]
most_frequent_item = arr.uniq.max_by{ |i| arr.count( i ) }
puts most_frequent_item
#=> 3
```

No need to even think about frequency mappings.

Comment: This is O(n*n) though, and the accepted answer is O(n)

Answer (score 8):

This is a duplicate of this question 
"[Ruby - Unique elements in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857915/ruby-unique-elements-in-array)".

Here is that question's solution:

```
group_by { |n| n }.values.max_by(&:size).first
```

That version seems to be even faster than Nilesh C's answer.  Here is the code I used to benchmark it (OS X 10.6 Core 2 2.4GHz MB).

Kudos to Mike Woodhouse for the (original) benchmarking code:

```
class Array
   def mode1
     group_by { |n| n }.values.max_by(&:size).first
   end
   def mode2
     freq = inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
     max = freq.values.max                   # we're only interested in the key(s) with the highest frequency
     freq.select { |k, f| f == max }         # extract the keys that have the max frequency
   end
end

arr = Array.new(1_0000) { |i| rand(100000) }    # something to test with

Benchmark.bm(30) do |r|
    (1..2).each do |i| r.report("mode#{i}") { 100.times do arr.send("mode#{i}").inspect; end }; end
end
```

And here are the results of the benchmark:

```
                                user     system      total        real
mode1                           1.830000   0.010000   1.840000 (  1.876642)
mode2                           2.280000   0.010000   2.290000 (  2.382117)
 mode1 = 70099
 mode2 = [[70099, 3], [70102, 3], [51694, 3], [49685, 3], [38410, 3], [90815, 3], [30551, 3], [34720, 3], [58373, 3]]
```

As you can see, this version is about 20% faster with the caveat of ignoring ties.  I also like the succinctness, I personally use it as-is without monkey patching all over the place.  :)

Answer (score 7):

Ruby versions >= 2.7 will have [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0.preview1/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally)

> Tallys the collection. Returns a hash where the keys are the elements
>   and the values are numbers of elements in the collection that
>   correspond to the key.

So, you can do

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3].tally
# => {1=>3, 2=>1, 3=>1}
```

Comment: Something new to ruby!

Answer (score 3):

if you are trying to avoid learning #inject (which you should not do...)

```
words = ['cat', 'dog', 'snake', 'dog']
count = Hash.new(0)

words.each {|word| count[word] += 1}
count.sort_by { |k,v| v }.last
```

but if I read this answer before, now I would know nothing about #inject and man, you need to know about #inject.

Answer (score 2):

```
idx = {}
[2,2,1,3,1].each { |i| idx.include?(i) ? idx[i] += 1 : idx[i] = 1}
```

This is just a simple indexer. You could replace the [2,2,1..] array with any sort of symbol/string based identifier, this wouldn't work with objects, you'd need to introduce a bit more complexity, but this is simple enough.

rereading your questions, this solution is a bit over-engineered since its going to return you an index of all occurrences, not just the one with the most.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another version that does give you the ties as a mode should:

```
def mode
  group_by {|x| x}.group_by {|k,v| v.size}.sort.last.last.map(&:first)
end
```

In other words, group the values, then group those kv pairs by the number of values, then sort *those* kv pairs, take the last (highest) size-group, and then unwind its values. I like `group_by`.

Comment: This is the only answer that is a single one-liner. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
def mode(array)

    count = []  # Number of times element is repeated in array
    output = [] 
    array.compact!
    unique = array.uniq
    j=0

    unique.each do |i|
        count[j] = array.count(i)
        j+=1
    end
    k=0
    count.each do |i|
        output[k] = unique[k] if i == count.max
        k+=1
    end  

    return output.compact.inspect
end

p mode([3,3,4,5]) #=> [3]

p mode([1,2,3]) #=> [1,2,3]

p mode([0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,3,3,3,3]) #=> [0,3]

p mode([-1,-1,nil,nil,nil,0]) #=> [-1]

p mode([-2,-2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1000]) #=> [-2]
```