# Ruby array subtraction?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Either I don't understand what happens when you subtract an array from an array, or something is wrong here.

What I have is a list of usernames (strings) in an array:

```
users.count - users.uniq.count    # => 9
users - users.uniq                # => []
```

I'm not sure how this is possible.

I'm essentially trying to find a list of the duplicates.  I realize there are other ways to go about this, just trying to understand Array operations better.

Here is the workaround code I used to get the same:

```
users.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|h,i| h[i] += 1; h}.select{|k,v| v > 1}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use

```
dups = users.select{|e| users.count(e) > 1 }.uniq
```

Or, to find only a single duplicate element:

```
firstDup = users.detect {|e| users.count(e) > 1 }
```

About the array subtraction, this may clarify:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
a - [1] # => []
```

Array subraction removes **all** occurences, not just one.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of [Array#-](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-2D) is quite correct. It

> Returns a new array that is a copy of the original array, removing any
>   items that also appear in other_ary.

The user list (with duplicates) without all the users is empty.

Coming from "[Ruby: How to find and return a duplicate value in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921999/ruby-how-to-find-and-return-a-duplicate-value-in-array)", the following seems to be good at finding duplicates in an Array:

```
users.detect {|e| users.rindex(e) != users.index(e) }
```

Comment: Just to increase performance by only doing 1 search:
```
   users.select.with_index { |e,i| users.rindex(e) != i }
```

And if the index also needed then
```
   users.each.with_index.select { |e,i| users.rindex(e) != i }
```