# How to select unique elements

Tags: ruby, arrays, uniq

I would like to extend the `Array` class with a `uniq_elements` method which returns those elements with multiplicity of one. I also would like to use closures to my new method as with `uniq`. For example:

```
t=[1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,9]
t.uniq_elements # => [1,3,5,6,8]
```

Example with closure:

```
t=[1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.4, 4.0, 4.2, 5.1, 5.7, 6.1, 6.2]
t.uniq_elements{|z| z.round} # => [2.0, 5.1]
```

Neither `t-t.uniq` nor `t.to_set-t.uniq.to_set` works. I don't care of speed, I call it only once in my program, so it can be a slow.

Comment: Not clear. Why is `5.7` included in the result of the second example?

Comment: becaused I missed, now I excluded it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Helper method**

This method uses the helper:

```
class Array
  def difference(other)
    h = other.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
    reject { |e| h[e] > 0 && h[e] -= 1 }
  end
end
```

This method is similar to [Array#-](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2D). The difference is illustrated in the following example:

```
a = [3,1,2,3,4,3,2,2,4]
b = [2,3,4,4,3,4]

a - b              #=> [1]
c = a.difference b #=> [1, 3, 2, 2]
```

As you see, `a` contains three 3's and `b` contains two, so the *first* two 3's  in `a` are removed in constructing `c` (`a` is not mutated). When `b` contains as least as many instances of an element as does `a`, `c` contains no instances of that element. To remove elements beginning at the end of `a`:

```
a.reverse.difference(b).reverse #=> [3, 1, 2, 2]
```

`Array#difference!` could be defined in the obvious way.

I have found many uses for this method: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584327/find-a-unique-element-in-a-compound-array/29585396#29585396), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966975/how-to-sort-an-array-by-amount-of-unique-groups-it-can-create/29969924#29969924), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886736/how-to-check-if-two-string-contains-the-same-character-in-ruby/29887358#29887358), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650041/get-an-array-of-arrays-with-unique-elements?nah=1#28820565), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611939/find-a-duplicate-in-an-array-ruby/30612075#30611939), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831946/matching-exact-elements-in-an-array-in-ruby/30832762#30832762), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104241/ruby-koan-182-greed-dice/31107937#comment50256692_31107937), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245594/excluding-first-element-by-value-from-array), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121533/method-for-splitting-array-into-element-remaining-elements-pairs/31896663#31896663), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035782/function-that-returns-the-number-of-letters-that-repeat-in-a-string/32038321#32038321), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864181/how-can-i-find-the-first-non-recurring-letter-of-a-string-in-ruby/32871760#32871760), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32729134/cant-get-ruby-method-to-pass-spec-for-anagram-method/32919483#32919483), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299204/combinaison-ruby-array-multidimensionnel-to-get-a-array-two-dimensional/33305906#33305906), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793393/return-similar-elements-of-array-in-ruby/33793640#33793640), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635399/ruby-remove-one-element-from-array/36637279#36637279), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682667/how-do-i-compare-integer-indexes-in-arrays-when-there-are-duplicate-values/36686250#36686250), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211679/most-efficient-way-to-count-duplicated-elements-between-two-arrays#comment61463467_36211679), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942564/ruby-comparing-numbers-using-a-multidimensional-array/38947157#38947157), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037626/how-to-find-which-items-in-a-massive-array-appear-more-than-once/39043960#39043960), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921999/ruby-how-to-find-and-return-a-duplicate-value-in-array/31354262#31354262), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078385/how-can-i-generate-a-percentage-for-a-regex-string-match-in-ruby), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645614/how-do-i-check-if-all-the-elements-in-my-array-occur-no-more-than-twice/41646208#41646208) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42008449/comparing-array-elements-including-duplicates/42015143#42015143).

I have [proposed](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11815) that this method be added to the Ruby core.

When used with `Array#-`, this method makes it easy to extract the unique elements from an array `a`:

```
a = [1,3,2,4,3,4]
u = a.uniq          #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
u - a.difference(u) #=> [1, 2]
```

This works because

```
a.difference(u)     #=> [3,4]
```

contains all the non-unique elements of `a` (each possibly more than once).

**Problem at Hand**

*Code*

```
class Array
  def uniq_elements(&prc)
    prc ||= ->(e) { e }
    a = map { |e| prc[e] }
    u = a.uniq
    uniques = u - a.difference(u)
    select { |e| uniques.include?(prc[e]) ? (uniques.delete(e); true) : false }
  end
end
```

*Examples*

```
t = [1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,9]
t.uniq_elements
  #=> [1,3,5,6,8]

t = [1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.4, 4.0, 4.2, 5.1, 5.7, 6.1, 6.2]
t.uniq_elements { |z| z.round }
  # => [2.0, 5.1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way.

**Code**

```
require 'set'

class Array
  def uniq_elements(&prc)
    prc ||= ->(e) { e }
    uniques, dups = {}, Set.new
    each do |e|
      k = prc[e]
      ((uniques.key?(k)) ? (dups << k; uniques.delete(k)) :
          uniques[k] = e) unless dups.include?(k)
    end
    uniques.values
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
t = [1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,9]
t.uniq_elements #=> [1,3,5,6,8]

t = [1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.4, 4.0, 4.2, 5.1, 5.7, 6.1, 6.2]
t.uniq_elements { |z| z.round } # => [2.0, 5.1]
```

**Explanation**

- if `uniq_elements` is called with a block, it is received as the proc `prc`.
- if `uniq_elements` is called without a block, `prc` is `nil`, so the first statement of the method sets `prc` equal to the default proc (lambda).
- an initially-empty hash, `uniques`, contains representations of the unique values.  The values are the unique values of the array `self`, the keys are what is returned when the proc `prc` is passed the array value and called: `k = prc[e]`.
- the set `dups` contains the elements of the array that have found to not be unique.  It is a set (rather than an array) to speed lookups.  Alternatively, if could be a hash with the non-unique values as keys, and arbitrary values.
- the following steps are performed for each element `e` of the array `self`:

  - `k = prc[e]` is computed.
  - if `dups` contains `k`, `e` is a dup, so nothing more needs to be done; else
  - if `uniques` has a key `k`, `e` is a dup, so `k` is added to the set `dups` and the element with key `k` is removed from `uniques`; else
  - the element `k=>e` is added to `uniques` as a candidate for a unique element.
- the values of `unique` are returned.

Comment: thx, I used this method till now, but it doesn't receive a block:
`def uelements(a)
  t=a.sort
  u=[]
  u.push t1[0] if t1[0] != t1[1]
  for i in 1..t.size-2 do
    u.push t[i] if t[i] != t[i+1] && t[i] != t[i-1]
  end
  u.push t[-1] if t[-2] != t[-1]
  return u
end`

Answer (score 1):

```
class Array
  def uniq_elements
    counts = Hash.new(0)

    arr = map do |orig_val|
      converted_val =  block_given? ? (yield orig_val) : orig_val
      counts[converted_val] += 1
      [converted_val, orig_val]
    end

    uniques = []

    arr.each do |(converted_val, orig_val)|
      uniques << orig_val if counts[converted_val] == 1
    end

    uniques
  end
end

t=[1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,9]
p t.uniq_elements

t=[1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.4, 4.0, 4.2, 5.1, 5.7, 6.1, 6.2]
p  t.uniq_elements { |elmt| elmt.round }

--output:--
[1, 3, 5, 6, 8]
[2.0, 5.1]
```

Array#uniq does not find non-duplicated elements, rather Array#uniq removes duplicates.

Comment: VII, after the `map` block, consider `arr.each_with_object([]) do |(converted_val, orig_val),uniques|...end`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Enumerable#tally`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally):

```rb
class Array
  def uniq_elements
    tally.select { |_obj, nb| nb == 1 }.keys
  end
end

t=[1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,9]
t.uniq_elements # => [1,3,5,6,8]
```

If you are using Ruby < 2.7, you can get `tally` with the [backports gem](https://github.com/marcandre/backports/#backports-library---)

```rb
require 'backports/2.7.0/enumerable/tally'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array
  def uniq_elements
    zip( block_given? ? map { |e| yield e } : self )
      .each_with_object Hash.new do |(e, v), h| h[v] = h[v].nil? ? [e] : false end
      .values.reject( &:! ).map &:first
  end
end

[1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,9].uniq_elements #=> [1, 3, 5, 6, 8]
[1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.4, 4.0, 4.2, 5.1, 5.7, 6.1, 6.2].uniq_elements &:round #=> [2.0, 5.1]
```

Comment: each_with_index() is not necessary.  You can just insert 1 every time. Also note: you traverse the array twice(the minimal number of times) but then you additionally have to call keys().

Comment: Now get rid of your Hash and use Hash.new(0) instead; there's no need to create all those arrays.

Comment: I've done that before your comment was written, but thanks for attentiveness.

Comment: Yeah, but I was thinking it the first time I read your post!  I still think mines more efficient...well, you nicely sidestep the map() call if there's no block given. Ahh..but yours won't work with the rounding example because you do not preserve the mapping between the original val and the converted val.

Answer (score 0):

1. Creating and calling a default proc is a waste of time, and
2. Cramming everything into one line using tortured constructs doesn't make the code more efficient--it just makes the code harder to understand.
3. In require statements, rubyists don't capitalize file names.

....

```
require 'set'

class Array
  def uniq_elements
    uniques = {}
    dups = Set.new

    each do |orig_val|
      converted_val =  block_given? ? (yield orig_val) : orig_val
      next if dups.include? converted_val 

      if uniques.include?(converted_val)  
        uniques.delete(converted_val)
        dups << converted_val
      else
        uniques[converted_val] = orig_val
      end
    end

    uniques.values
  end
end


t=[1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,9]
p t.uniq_elements

t=[1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.4, 4.0, 4.2, 5.1, 5.7, 6.1, 6.2]

p  t.uniq_elements {|elmt|
  elmt.round
}

--output:--
[1, 3, 5, 6, 8]
[2.0, 5.1]
```

Comment: Thanks, 7. I initially had `next if...`, as you suggest, but switched to `unless` because the code was short, though `next` may read better.  I prefer using the proc, in part because `unique_elements(&prc)` tells the reader immediately that a parameter may be being passed, and the first line clarifies that; a naked `unique_elements` suggests the opposite, until the reader sees `yield`. I downcased `set`.

Comment: `I prefer using the proc, because tells the reader immediately that a parameter may be being passed`  Fair enough, but ruby's syntax was created to allow you to pass a method into another method without specifying an argument.  Also, frivolous method calls aren't free.   `switched to unless`  I follow 'Perl Best Practices' in regards to unless--it's an abomination.  In any case, nice solution using only a single traversal of the array.