# How to sort an array by amount of unique groups it can create

Tags: ruby

I have no idea how to formulate the question correctly, but what I want is the following:

Let's say there's an array like

```
[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]
```

How can I sort it, until this becomes the output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1]
```

---

To make the output a bit more readable:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3],[1]]
```

What I've come up so far is:

```
array = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]
array.group_by{|n| n }.values.transpose.flatten
```

But this throws an error due to not having the same amount of numbers.

Can anybody help?

Comment: It's not so hard to state your question succinctly and unambiguously: "Given an array `a` and an empty array `b`, I wish to obtain an array `c` comprised of the unique elements of `a`, add `c` to `b`, remove one of each element of `c` from `a`, repeat these steps until `a` is empty, and return `b`." Once stated clearly, translating each element of the question to code is fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it took a while to do this but here is what you want:

```
array = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]

a = array.group_by{|n| n }.values.sort_by(&:length).reverse

a.each{|q| (a[0].size-q.size).times{q<<nil}}

a.sort.transpose.flatten.compact
```

it produces:

```
  => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

*you have 3 number of twos

Comment: This works, but only if `a[0]` is the largest group.

Comment: see the edit now. the sub array with maximum length will always be on the first index

Comment: Yes it is in this specific  case. But let's say your array contains 5 2's, like: `[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]` . Than sort will not sort on the maximum length. But thanks for the answer, I came up with my own answer which does hold that thing into account. It's just a matter of finetuning.

Answer (score 1):

```
▶ array = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]
▶ tap = array.group_by(&:to_i).values.sort do |i, j| 
▷   result = j.length <=> i.length
▷   result.zero? ? i <=> j : result
▷ end
▶ tap.map do |e| 
▷   e.fill nil, (e.length...tap.first.length)
▷ end.transpose.flatten.compact
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Came up with my own answer as well.

```
array = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]

# group all the values in single array
a = array.group_by{|n| n }.values.sort{|a,b| b.size <=> a.size }

# fill every other space in the other subarrays with nil
a.each{|q| q.fill(nil, (a[0].size...q.size)) }

# transpose, flatten and remove all the nil values
a.transpose.flatten.compact
```

If anyone knows a 'smaller' more readable answer, please tell.

Answer (score 0):

Let `arr` be your array. Then:

```
def transform(arr)
  a = arr.sort
  b = []
  until a.empty?
    u = a.uniq
    b << u
    a = a.difference(u)
  end
  b
end
```

The helper `Array#difference` is defined in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987054/how-to-select-unique-elements).

Let's try it:

```
transform(arr)
  #=> [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3], [1]]
```