# Counting matching elements in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given two arrays of equal size, how can I find the number of matching elements disregarding the position?
*For example:*

1. `[0,0,5]` and `[0,5,5]` would return a match of `2` since there is one `0` and one `5` in common;
2. `[1,0,0,3]` and `[0,0,1,4]` would return a match of `3` since there are two matches of `0` and one match of `1`;
3. `[1,2,2,3]` and `[1,2,3,4]` would return a match of `3`.

I tried a number of ideas, but they all tend to get rather gnarly and convoluted. I'm guessing there is some nice Ruby idiom, or perhaps a regex that would be an elegant answer to this solution.

Comment: My first guess would have been `array_one & array_two`.length, but that doesn't include unique elements

Comment: Good question, well stated.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Totally agree with you, but title is vague – it is unlikely that people with the same issue will reach this post. P.S. I was also having a bad time formulating a non-cumbersome title for this..

Comment: @suslov, you have a point. How about, "Determine the number of elements in one array that map 1-1 to the same element in a second array."?

Comment: Joe, after reading your profile I thought you'd be interested in [this picture](http://media.news.harvard.edu/gazette/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Turing_Mark-I_380.jpg) of me working on my first computer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, love that photo! That's just awesome. Sorry to you guys for the poorly worded question, but I had a devil of a time expressing in words what was easier shown in a few example. Appreciate all of your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish it with [`count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-count):

```
a.count{|e| index = b.index(e) and b.delete_at index }
```

[**Demonstration**](http://repl.it/s03/8)

or with [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
a.inject(0){|count, e| count + ((index = b.index(e) and b.delete_at index) ? 1 : 0)}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://repl.it/s03/7)

or with [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) and [`length`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-length) (*or it's alias* – [`size`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-size)):

```
a.select{|e| (index = b.index(e) and b.delete_at index)}.size
```

[**Demonstration**](http://repl.it/s03/9)

Results:

1. `a, b = [0,0,5], [0,5,5]` *output:* `=> 2`;
2. `a, b = [1,2,2,3], [1,2,3,4]` *output:* `=> 3`;
3. `a, b = [1,0,0,3], [0,0,1,4]` *output* `=> 3`.

Comment: I think this is the solution! I need to run my rspec's on it, as I got bit by a number of edge cases in my own attempt, but I'm keeping my fingers crossed. Will let you know after my suite runs. In the meantime, thank you very much.

Comment: It passed my tests! Thank you again, suslov, I've credited you in my source code. My obliged.

Comment: Nice. You can reduce the work with `a.select{|e| ndx = b.index(e) &&  b.delete_at ndx }.count`. Note this doesn't work if `nil` elements are present. Also, it mutates `b`, so you may wish to operate on a copy of `b`.

Comment: Wait a minute. I may have spoken too soon :-).

Comment: Yes. (I think the latter is more in keeping with the way `inject` works.)

Comment: I just have to say that `select` is a **really** nice piece of ruby code! My original motivation to ask here was to learn the "Ruby way" of doing it, and I was well schooled. Just beautiful! I'm amazed, actually. Thanks again, my code is working beautifully and I am happily adding new features rather than banging my head.

Answer (score 3):

```
(arr1 & arr2).map { |i| [arr1.count(i), arr2.count(i)].min }.inject(0, &:+)
```

Here `(arr1 & arr2)` return list of uniq values that both arrays contain, `arr.count(i)` counts the number of items `i` in the array.

Comment: That wouldn't work, because you can have more than one of the same value

Comment: ah, sorry. i misunderstood the problem. just a moment. I'll update it

Comment: updated. what is interesting, I haven't known about `count(i)` before :)

Comment: Excellent! Best answer so far, imo, but I would suggest a slight simplification: `arr1.uniq.reduce(0) { |t,e| t+[arr1.count(e), arr2.count(e)].min }`.

Answer (score 2):

Another use for the mighty (and much needed) `Array#difference`, which I defined in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987054/how-to-select-unique-elements). This method is similar to `Array#-`. The difference between the two methods is illustrated in the following example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,3,2,4,2]
b = [2,3,4,4,4]
a - b          #=> [1]
a.difference b #=>  [1, 3, 2, 2]
```

For the present application:

```
def number_matches(a,b)
  left_in_b = b
  a.reduce(0) do |t,e|
    if left_in_b.include?(e)
      left_in_b = left_in_b.difference [e]
      t+1
    else
      t
    end
  end
end

number_matches [0,0,5],   [0,5,5]   #=> 2
number_matches [1,0,0,3], [0,0,1,4] #=> 3
number_matches [1,0,0,3], [0,0,1,4] #=> 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [multiset](https://github.com/maraigue/multiset) gem:

```
(Multiset.new(a) & Multiset.new(b)).size
```

Multiset is like [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html), but allows duplicate values.  `&` is the "set intersection" operator (return all things that are in both sets).

Comment: From rubygems.org description: Unlike ordinary set(see Ruby documentation for "set" library), multiset can contain two or more same items. Set[:a,:b,:c,:b,:b,:c] # => #<Set: {:b, :c, :a}> Multiset[:a,:b,:c,:b,:b,:c] # => #<Multiset:#3 :b, #2 :c, #1 :a> Multisets are typically used for counting elements and their appearances in collections. Very interesting. Thank you for making me aware of this gem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an ideal answer, because it's a bit complex, but...

```
def count(arr)
  arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
end

def matches(a1, a2)
  m = 0
  a1_counts = count(a1)
  a2_counts = count(a2)
  a1_counts.each do |e, c|
    m += [a1_counts, a2_counts].min
  end
  m
end
```

Basically, first write a method that creates a hash from an array of the number of times each element appears. Then, use those to sum up the smallest number of times each element appears in both arrays.

Comment: You forgot a closing `] in `matches +=` line

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I'm just throwing this together off the top of my head, so there might be syntax issues.

Comment: I tried this in irb. Now I'm getting `undefined method '+' for nil:Nilclass`

Comment: There we go. Should have gotten my code working before answering, but I think it's working now.

Comment: Your method `count` is sometimes called a "counting hash" and is conventionally written, `def count(arr);
 arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {  |e,h| h[e] += 1 }; end`.

Comment: You realize you are calling `count` over and over again?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks, I figured there was probably a standard way of doing that. While there are already other, better answers, I've revised to take your comments into account.