# Excluding first element by value from array

Tags: ruby

I want to get something like this:

```
a                       =  [0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0]
a.except(1)           # => [0,0,0,1,0,1,0]
a                     # => [0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0]
a.except(1).except(1) # => [0,0,0,0,1,0]
```

As you see, the first element of `a` that equals the argument of `except` is removed from `a`.

I can do:

```
tmp_a = a.dup
tmp_a.delete_at(a.index(1))
tmp_a
```

but in my opinion, it looks like smell. Is there more elegant one-line solution? (In other words - how to define method "except" for Array?)

**UPD**

I solved this problem so

```
class Array
  def except(elem)
    dup.tap{|a| a.delete_at(a.index(elem))}
  end
end
```

what do you think?

Comment: Write a method that encapsulates the element find and slicing. No reason to dupe the array, just take the elements on either side of the value.

Comment: Meta-comment: down-boring an answer because of a misunderstanding seems extreme to me-just comment to clarify and users will police their own content.

Comment: I didn't downvote, however, one of the possible reasons for downvoting mentioned in the tooltip for the downvote button is "This question is unclear", so, if a user feels that the question is unclear, downvoting is perfectly fine. And even if that one user happens to be mistaken, well, there are 4.1 million others which can upvote.

Comment: What's unclear about this question?

Comment: Could the people who put this question on hold please elaborate what's unclear about it? The Question is pretty much spot-on...

Comment: Gena, a couple of points about your method `Array#except`: 1) `index`'s argument should be `elem`; 2) `self.` is optional. That is, you write: `dup.tap { |a| a.delete_at(a.index(elem)) }`.

Comment: Gena, I liked your use of `tap`, so modified my code for `Array#difference` (at link given in my answer) to use `tap` in place of `cpy = dup`, then `cpy` as the last line. I like the sound of the method, so much so that sometimes I write `obj.tap{}.tap{}.tap { |x| ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's so "hacky" about your solution?

This is also what first came to my mind (started hacking away before reading the entire question :P)

```
class Array
  def except(elem)
    tmp = self.dup
    tmp.delete_at(self.index(elem))
    tmp
  end
end
```

Or you can use the power of `delete_if` (including `count` I stole from @mudasobwa 's answer:

```
class Array
  def except(elem, count = 1)
    tmp = self.dup
    memo = 0
    tmp.delete_if { |e| elem == e && (memo += 1) <= count }
  end
end
```

Or you can `slice` your array to bits:

```
class Array
  def except(elem)
    index = self.index(elem)
    self.slice(0, index) + self.slice(index + 1, self.length)
  end
end
```

Comment: Upvoted for `slice` (which I would rewrite as `self[0...index] + self[index+1..-1]`).

Comment: you can replace your `slice` calls with: `reject.with_index { |_, i| i == index }`

Comment: This would be the same as the `delete_if` solution.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks, it seems good. Look my own solution under UPD in question

Comment: Ah, very interesting! Didn't know about `tap`! However, I actually prefer your first version because it's much more readable. Technically it's the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Array
  def except what, count = 1
    memo = 0
    map do |e| 
      what == e && (memo += 1) <= count ? nil : e
    end.compact
  end
end
```

The above will remove `count` occurences of `what`:

```
a.except(1, 2) 
#⇒ [0,0,0,0,1,0]
```

Comment: Cool solution, but look out if your array looks like this: `[0, nil, 0, 0, nil, 0, nil, 0]`. But then, who has `nil`s in his arrays anyways...

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

```
a.difference [1]
  #=> [0,0,0,1,0,1,0] 

a #=> [0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0]
```

where `Array#difference` is defined in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987054/how-to-select-unique-elements).

Comment: It is the same as that of my solution under UPD in question, cool, thanks

Comment: When the argument of `difference` is an array containing a single element, yes.