# create subarray from sequence

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have array that looks like

```
[nil, nil, nil, nil, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 17, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 50, 51]
```

I want to "unflatten" it, so it'd look like

```
[[5,6,7,8,9,10,11],[17], [50,51]]
```

What would be the easiest way to achieve that?

Comment: @CarySwoveland You're right. Bad move by me. Will wait for more answers and mark most interesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arr.slice_before(&:nil?).map(&:compact).reject(&:empty?)
```

Just out of curiosity, `O(N)`:

```
arr.inject([[]]) do |memo, e| 
  e ? memo.last << e : (memo << [] unless memo.last.empty?)
  memo
end
```

Or, with modern ruby goodness:

```
arr.each_with_object([[]]) do |e, memo| 
  e && memo.last << e || (memo << [] unless memo.last.empty?)
end
```

And, totally out of curiosity (it’s a joke, please, do not use):

```
JSON.parse arr.to_json
              .gsub(/\D{2,}/, '],[')
              .gsub(/\A\D+/, '[[')
              .gsub(/\D+\z/, ']]')
```

Comment: Nice one. I tried the second approach but couldn't get it into such an elegant form.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I added the most sophisticated method.

Comment: Here's another curiosity. If the elements are `nil` or integers, we could write `arr.join(' ').strip.split(/\s{2,}/).map { |s| s.split(/\s/).map(&:to_i) }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good catch!

Answer (score 3):

I thought about

```
a.slice_when { |e1, e2| e1 != e2 && e2.nil? }.map(&:compact)
# => [[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [17], [50, 51]]
```

Comment: I love [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when). I believe we got it with Ruby 2.2.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, it is from 2.2.2.

Comment: There is `Enumerable#chunk_while`, which I proposed, coming in Ruby 2.3: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10769.

Comment: @sawa, that will be a welcome addition. I've been thinking of proposing the addition of a method [Array#difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987054/how-to-select-unique-elements). Could you give me a link to where you proposed `chunk_by`, so I can see the procedure?

Comment: Cary, I misstyped the name. It is `chunk_while`. The change is [here](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi?view=revision&revision=50889). Cary and Arup: `chunk_while` is the negation of `slice_when`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) for this:

```
arr = [nil, nil, nil, nil, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 17,
       nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 50, 51]

arr.chunk(&:nil?).reject(&:first).map(&:last)
  #=> [[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [17], [50, 51]]
```

The steps:

```
enum = arr.chunk(&:nil?)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fd303042440>:each>
```

We can examine the elements of the enumerator `enum` by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[true,  [nil, nil, nil, nil]],
  #    [false, [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]],
  #    [true,  [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]],
  #    [false, [17]],
  #    [true,  [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]],
  #    [false, [50, 51]]]
```

Two more steps:

```
a = enum.reject(&:first)
  #=> [[false, [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]],
  #    [false, [17]],
  #    [false, [50, 51]]] 
a.map(&:last)
  #=> [[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [17], [50, 51]]
```

**Edit:** Thanks to @Stefan, today I learned something new about the way `chunk` handles `nil`s. As he suggests, we can simplify this to:

```
arr.chunk { |e| e && false }.map(&:last)
  #=> [[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [17], [50, 51]]
```

Well, maybe that's not exactly what he said, but it works just as well. (My variant is more of a head-scratcher.)

Comment: A slight variation: `a.chunk { |e| e && true }.map(&:last)`