# Can't get Ruby method to pass spec for Anagram method

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get this to pass spec to verify if an argument is an anagram of another word, but it's just not happening.

- I can get the string (starting with just one sting word) into an array, and whether it's one or multiple words,
- It then iterates through the array over each word.
- Using the If statement to compare if the sorted object is equal to the sorted argument.
- Applied .join, since it came out one letter at a time in irb, but it's still not happening, with or without .join.

  ```
    class String
      define_method(:anagrams) do |check_word|
        words = self.downcase
        check_word = check_word.downcase
        words_array = words.split(" ")

        words_array.each do |word|
          if (word.chars.sort) == (check_word.chars.sort)
            true
          else
            false
          end
        end
      end
    end
  ```

Any ideas why it's broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
words_array.each do |word|
  if (word.chars.sort) == (check_word.chars.sort)
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

I'm assuming you want to `return true` if any words are anagrams. You're currently not explicitly returning.

Better Ruby syntax would be `words_array.any? { |word| word.chars.sort == check_word.chars.sort) }`

OR

```
words_array.each do |word|
  return true if (word.chars.sort) == (check_word.chars.sort)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to see if two words `w1` and `w2` are anagrams of each other:

```
def anagrams?(w1, w2)
  w1.size == w2.size && w1.chars.difference(w2.chars).empty?
end
```

where `Array#difference` is how I defined it in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987054/how-to-select-unique-elements).

`Array#difference` is similar to [Array#-](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2D). The difference is illustrated in the following example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,3,2,2,4]
b = [2,3,4,4,4]

a     -      b #=> [1]
a.difference b #=> [1, 3, 2, 2]
```

Let's try it:

```
anagrams?("tops", "stop")  #=> true
anagrams?("tops", "stopz") #=> false
anagrams?("tops", "stopz") #=> false
anagrams?("tops", "sto")   #=> false
```