# How can I find the first non-recurring letter of a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string `"teststring"`. I want to find first non-recurring character in Ruby.

I have this Python code:

```
def first_non_repeat_character(teststring)
    unique=[]
    repeated=[]
    for character in teststring:
        if character in unique:
            unique.remove(character)
            repeated.append(character)
        else:
            if not character in repeated:
                unique.append(character)
    if len(unique):
        return unique[0]
    else: 
        return false
```

Comment: Fix your indentation, as of now, this is completely unreadable. This is not Ruby, this is attempt at Python. Also what do you mean by *first non repeating character*? A character which was not found so far? Or a character, not followed by itself (`aa`)?

Comment: i am trying to find out character which was not found so far i know i did it in python.....as i am new to ruby i dont know how to do this in ruby

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def first_non_repeat_character(string)
  string.chars.find { |character| string.count(character) == 1 }
end

first_non_repeat_character('teststring') # => "e"
```

Comment: +1, because I suspect this is the most performant answer so far because it relies on fast String methods rather than chained Hash/Array methods.

Comment: @CodeGnome depending on the string's length and the position of the non-recurring character (if any), this approach traverses the string multiple times because of the nested `count`.

Answer (score 1):

That should do the trick:

```
def first_non_repeat_character(teststring)
  group = teststring.chars.group_by {|i| i}.find {|letter, group| group.one? }
  group && group.first
end
```

Since ruby 2.2.1 you can use `group_by(&:itself)`

Comment: No this is not working, for 'teststring' answer should be 'e' and if I pass 'letter' instead the answer should be 'l'

Comment: @vidal - this is exactely what it returns for those inputs. o_0 which ruby version do you use?

Comment: I am using ruby 2.2.2

Comment: So what results do you get, it all works on my machine.

Comment: Now I am getting the answer, I was not calling the function properly.

Comment: Too bad, I was hoping this was some cross-platform incompatibility. Anyway, the main difference between this and ndn's answer is reduced complexity: O(n) vs O(n^2)

Comment: You can write `group_by(&:itself)` and use `find` instead of `select` (thus avoiding the method's second line)

Comment: BTW, interesting use of `one?`

Comment: @Stefan - So they finally released `itself` method? That's awesome, was waiting for it for a while. :) As per `find` vs `select` - I can't believe I missed that. 00

Comment: @Stefan The only caveat is that Object#itself is new in Ruby 2.2.0. Just something future visitors should be aware of.

Comment: But I was wrong about the second line, you still need it.

Comment: @CodeGnome or visitors from the past ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With a nod to @BroiSatse for the basic idea, I suggest the following variation in his answer for chaining in an irb or pry console if you have Ruby 2.2+ with the new [Object#itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-itself) method:

```
'teststring'.chars.group_by(&:itself).values.select { |v| v.one? }.flatten.first
#=> "e"
```

The nice thing about this approach (as opposed to defining a method) is that it's easy to backtrack up the method chain for debugging. If you don't get the answer you expect, just keep removing the tail of the method chain until you find the problem.

Comment: Note that the second one will raise an error if the string contains only duplicates due to `nil[0]`.

Comment: @Stefan Fixed. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Another one:

```
'teststring'.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c, h| h[c] += 1 }.key(1)
#=> "e"
```

#### Step by step:

[`each_char`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-each_char) traverses each character:

```
'teststring'.each_char.to_a
#=> ["t", "e", "s", "t", "s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"]
```

[`with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) passes a `Hash` with a default value of `0` to the block on order to count each character (returning the hash):

```
'teststring'.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c, h| h[c] += 1 }
#=> {"t"=>3, "e"=>1, "s"=>2, "r"=>1, "i"=>1, "n"=>1, "g"=>1}
```

[`key`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html#method-i-key) returns the key (i.e. character) for the given value (i.e. with a count of 1)

```
'teststring'.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c, h| h[c] += 1 }.key(1)
#=> "e"
```

Possible caveat: although the implementation returns the *first* key for the given value, the documentation says:

> Returns the key of *an occurrence* of a given value.

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

```
str = 'teststring'

arr = str.chars
(arr - (arr.difference(arr.uniq))).first
  #= "e"
```

where `Array#difference` is defined in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987054/how-to-select-unique-elements).

`Array#difference` is similar to `Array#-`. The difference is illustrated in the following example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,3,2,2,4]
b = [2,3,4,4,4]

a     -      b #=> [1]
a.difference b #=> [1, 3, 2, 2]
```

`arr.difference(arr.uniq)` therefore returns an array of all elements `e` of `arr` for which `arr.count(e) > 1`.

`arr.difference(arr.uniq)` returns the recurring characters, so

```
arr - arr.difference(arr.uniq)
```

returns the non-recurring characters, ordered as they are ordered in `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample that takes into account if there are capital letters. For example if you pass in

```
"sTresst" => "r"

def  first_non_repeating_letter(s) 
  s.each_char do |char|
    return char if s.downcase.count(char.downcase) < 2
  end
  ""
end
```