# Combinaison ruby Array multidimensionnel to get a Array two dimensional

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a Array multidimensionnel like:

```
[[1, 1, 4], [2],[2, 3]]
```

How to get a combinaison each element except the combinaison in the same array:  [1, 1],[1, 4],[2, 3]

I want to get:

```
[1, 2],[1, 3],[4, 2],[4, 3],[2, 3]
```

Thanks.

Comment: why you have [2,3] at the end but you don't have [1,4] ? Did you try something?

Comment: @radubogdan, presumably, `[a,b]` should be included if, for some `i` and `j`, `i<j`, `a` is in `arr[i]` and  `b` is in `arr[j]` where `arr` is the given array of arrays. Doug. Is that correct?

Comment: Doug, when you give an example it's helpful to assign each input object to a variable; for example, `arr = [[1,1,...]`. That way, readers can refer to `arr` in answers and comments without having to define it.

Comment: Shouldn't the array returned include `[2,2]`? If so, please edit; if not, please edit to explain why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is:

```
[[1, 1, 4], [2],[2, 3]].combination(2).flat_map {|x,y| x.product(y)}.uniq
# => [[1, 2], [4, 2], [1, 3], [4, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3]]
```

---

**Step by step**

1. ```
   step1 = [[1, 1, 4], [2],[2, 3]].combination(2) 
   # => [[[1, 1, 4], [2]], [[1, 1, 4], [2, 3]], [[2], [2, 3]]]
   ```
2. ```
   step2 = step1.flat_map {|x,y| x.product(y)}
   # => [[1, 2], [1, 2], [4, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 2], [4, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3]]
   ```
3. ```
   result = step2.uniq
   # => [[1, 2], [4, 2], [1, 3], [4, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3]]
   ```

---

**Update**

For full uniqueness you could use:

```
[[1, 1, 4], [2],[2, 3, 4]].combination(2).flat_map {|x,y| x.product(y)}.map(&:sort).uniq
```

Comment: if i have : [[1, 1, 4], [2],[2, 3, 4]].combination(2).map {|x,y| x.product(y)}.flatten(1).sort.uniq, i get [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4]], so [2, 4] and [4, 2] is not uniq

Comment: Check my update. Next time please describe what you want with all details

Comment: Thanks, I get it too.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [[1, 1, 4], [2], [2, 3]]

a = arr.map(&:uniq)
(arr.size-1).times.flat_map { |i| arr[i].product(arr[i+1..-1].flatten.uniq)}.uniq
  #=> [[1,2],[1,3],[4,2],[4,3],[2,2],[2,3]]
```

Here's another way that uses the method `Array#difference` that I defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987054/how-to-select-unique-elements):

```
arr.flatten.combination(2).to_a.difference(arr.flat_map { |a| a.combination(2).to_a }).uniq
```

`Array#difference` is similar to [Array#-](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-2D). The difference is illustrated in the following example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,3,2,2,4]
b = [2,3,4,4,4]

a     -      b #=> [1]
a.difference b #=> [1, 3, 2, 2]
```