# Return similar elements of array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, duplicates, partial

Say I have such an array:

```
arr = ['footballs_jumba_10', 'footballs_jumba_11', 'footballs_jumba_12',
       'footballs_jumba_14', 'alpha_romeo_11', 'alpha_romeo_12',
       'alpha_juliet_10', 'alpha_juliet_11']
```

If I wanted to return duplicates, (assuming any of these strings in the array were exactly identical, I would just

```
return arr.detect{ |a| arr.count(a) > 1 }
```

but, what if I wanted to get only duplicates of the first 10 characters of each element of the array, without knowing the variations beforehand? Like this:

```
['footballs_', 'alpha_rome', 'alpha_juli']
```

Comment: Your example would have been better had you included a string whose first 10 characters were unique, as it would not have been returned in the desired result. (Too late now to change it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite straightforward with the method `Arry#difference` that I proposed in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987054/how-to-select-unique-elements):

```
arr << "Let's add a string that appears just once"
  #=> ["footballs_jumba_10", "footballs_jumba_11", "footballs_jumba_12",
  #    "footballs_jumba_14", "alpha_romeo_11", "alpha_romeo_12",
  #    "alpha_juliet_10", "alpha_juliet_11", "Let's add a string that appears just once"]

a = arr.map { |s| s[0,10] }
  #=> ["footballs_", "footballs_", "footballs_", "footballs_", "alpha_rome",
  #    "alpha_rome", "alpha_juli", "alpha_juli", "Let's add "] 
b = a.difference(a.uniq)
  #=> ["footballs_", "footballs_", "footballs_", "alpha_rome", "alpha_juli"] 
b.uniq
  #=> ["footballs_", "alpha_rome", "alpha_juli"]
```

Comment: Simple, straight-forward, and worked with a slice and a bit of regex. Thanks mate!

Comment: You might also consider a twig of parsley and a dash of oregano.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq):

```
arr.map {|e| e[0..9]}.uniq
# => ["footballs_", "alpha_rome", "alpha_juli"]
```

Comment: With `arr << "add a unique string"`, `arr.map {|e| e[0..9]}.uniq #=> ["footballs_", "alpha_rome", "alpha_juli", "add a uniq"]`, but only duplicates are wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```rb
def partial_duplicates(elements)
  unique = {}
  duplicates = {}

  elements.each do |e|
    partial = e[0..9]

      # If the element is in the hash, it is a duplicate.
      if first_element = unique[partial]
        duplicates[first_element] = true
        duplicates[e] = true
      else
        # include the element as unique
        unique[partial] = e
      end
  end

  duplicates.keys
end
```

This will return unique duplicates. If you want all the duplicates, you can just use an `Array`.

Also, this returns all the full representations of each duplicate as it seems more useful and probably what you want:

```rb
partial_duplicates(arr)
=> ["footballs_jumba_10", "footballs_jumba_11", "footballs_jumba_12", "footballs_jumba_14", "alpha_romeo_11", "alpha_romeo_12", "alpha_juliet_10", "alpha_juliet_11"]
```

If you want only the partial duplicates you can change the condition to:

```rb
if unique[partial]
  duplicates[partial] = true
else
  unique[partial] = true
end
```

then:

```rb
partial_duplicates(arr)
=> ["footballs_", "alpha_rome", "alpha_juli"]
```

Comment: Since `e` is a string and `duplicates` is a hash, you can't write `duplicates << e`, but you're on the right track. I suggest you make `unique` and `duplicates` sets (`require 'set'; unique = Set.new`). You could write `duplicates.add(e)` (or its alias `duplicates << e`)  to add `e` to the set but [Set#add?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F) would be better, as it both adds the element if it's not already in the set and tells you if it was added. Your last line is different and gives the wrong answer when `arr` contains a unique element. Test!

Comment: Thanks for the tips Cary. `duplicates << e` was a mistake indeed. But since `Set` actually uses hashes in its implementation, I decided to keep the hash, thus not needing the extra `require`. As for the last suggestion, I removed it entirely.

Comment: I don't think avoiding a `require` is a good reason to use phoney hashes rather than sets. By that argument you would never use sets, but we have them for just this type of situation. It's analogous to replacing sets in mathematics with functions having certain properties. It would make the math harder to follow with no advantage. (It probably would also spark a rash of suicides among mathematicians. Fortunately, most Rubiests are not that passionate.) I would be interested in the views of other readers about this.

Comment: Cary, my decision to use a hash in this case is simply one of simplifying the code in this example. I don't see how a `Set` makes this example simpler or more useful. And the *phoney* hashes as you mentioned it, is basically how [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add) is implemented.