# ruby Remove one element from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to remove (only one) element by value from my array.

example :

```
x = [1,2,3,2]
x.remove(2)


result: x= [1,3]
```

But, i want to get `[1,3,2]`.

thanks

Comment: when you call `1` do u want to remove specific number or first number of array ?

Comment: you can use `.delete_at(index of array)` for that, or u can keep uniq like from `[1,2,3,4,1]` to make to make it `[1,2,3,4]`. just call `x.uniq`.

Comment: i do not want to keep uniq array, i just need to delete the number that the customer enter, if i have x = [1,1,1], i want to keep [1,1]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As  @7urkm3n mentioned in the comments, you can use `x.delete_at` to delete the first occurance

```
x.delete_at(x.index 2)
```

---

```
> x = [1,2,3,2]
=> [1, 2, 3, 2] 
> x.delete_at(x.index 2)
=> 2 
> x
=> [1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: I was thinking about perf of delete_at Vs. slice! ... they should be ~ the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice!(index, 1)`. You can get the 1st index of the element you want to delete by using `index(element)`

In your case you just have to do: `x.slice!(x.index(2), 1)` (or, as already mentioned, `delete_at` just providing the index)

Answer (score 0):

You could write

```
x = [1,2,3,2]
x.difference([2])
  #=> [1, 3, 2]
```

where `Array#difference` is as I've defined it my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987054/how-to-select-unique-elements). Because of the wide potential application of the method I've [proposed](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11815) it be added to the Ruby core.

Suppose

```
x = [1,2,3,2,1,2,4,2]
```

and you wished to remove the first `1`, the first two `2`'s and the `4`. To do that you would write

```
x.difference([1,2,2,4])
  #=> [3, 1, 2, 2]
```

Note that

```
x.difference([1,2,2,4,4,5])
  #=> [3, 1, 2, 2]
```

gives the same result.

To remove the *last* `1`, the *last* two `2`s and and the `4`, write

```
x.reverse.difference([1,2,2,4]).reverse
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 2]
```