# Ruby - Comparing numbers using a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array, iteration

I'm working on a problem where I need to compare a number to an array of numbers seeing if 3 of the 4 numbers match.

For example:

```
winning_numbers = [["2537"], ["1294"], ["5142"]]

my_number = "1234"
```

If the comparison has 3 matching numbers return true. If the comparison has less than 3 or an exact match return false.

From what I've read I'm using a multi-dimensional array, however I don't understand how to loop through each array one number at at time, so that I can compare it to my number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this that returns all matching numbers:

```
winning_numbers.select do |number| 
  (number.first.split(//) & my_number.split(//)).size >= 3
end
#=> [["1294"], ["5142"]]
```

You might want to use `find` instead of `select`, when you are only interested into the first matching `winning_number`.

Comment: This does not work when there are duplicate digits. For example, if `winning_numbers = [["1111"]]; my_number = "1112"`, you return an empty array, though `[["1111"]]` is a match.

Answer (score 0):

If there were no duplicate digits we could use array intersection:

```
def triple?(winning_numbers, my_number)
  my_number_arr = my_number.chars
  winning_numbers.any? { |(w)| w.chars & my_number_arr).size == 3 }
end

winning_numbers = [["2537"], ["1294"], ["5142"]]
my_number = "1234"

triple?(winning_numbers, my_number) #=> true, matches "1294"
```

Alternatively, instead of `w.chars & my_number_arr).size == 3`, we could write

```
(w.chars - my_number_arr).size == 1 # (4-3=1)
```

This does not work, however, when strings have duplicate digits, which, of course, must be accounted for.

I [have proposed](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11815) that a method `Array#difference` be adopted as a Ruby core method. It would be perfect for this problem. See my answer at [Array#difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987054/how-to-select-unique-elements) for examples of its uses.

```
def triple?(winning_numbers, my_number)
  my_number_arr = my_number.chars
  winning_numbers.any? { |(w)| puts my_number_arr.difference(w.chars).size == 1 }
end

winning_numbers = [["2537"], ["1294"], ["5142"]]
my_number = "1234"

triple?(winning_numbers, my_number) #=> true, matches "1294"
```

Another example that includes duplicate digits:

```
winning_numbers = [["1551"], ["1594"], ["1141"]]

triple?(winning_numbers, my_number) # matches "1141"
```

and an example where there is no match on three digits:

```
winning_numbers = [["1551"], ["1594"], ["1561"]]

triple?(winning_numbers, my_number) #=> false (no match)
```