# How to find which items in a MASSIVE array appear more than once?

Tags: arrays, ruby, performance, sorting, unique

This is a very simple question; which items appear in the list more than once?

```
array = ["mike", "mike", "mike", "john", "john", "peter", "clark"]
```

The correct answer is `["mike", "john"]`.

Seems like we can just do:

```
array.select{ |e| ary.count(e) > 1 }.uniq
```

Problems solved. But wait! What if the array is REALLY big:

```
1_000_000.times { array.concat("1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('')) }
```

It just so happens I need to figure out how to do this in a reasonable amount of time. We're talking millions and millions of records.

For what it's worth, this massive array is actually a sum of 10-20 smaller arrays. If it's easier to compare those, let me know - I'm stumped.

We're talking 10,000 to 10,000,000 lines per file, hundreds of files.

Comment: Bit of a brainstorm, but what if we fed those values into a hash table, then if they start conflicting, we assume that it's a duplicate?

Comment: Brainstorm continued: The assumed 32-bit hashes of 1,000,000,000 entries would require a table of up to four gigabyte. This could be boiled down to 116 megabyte by using a bitset where each bit represents an occupied hash. This approach would require two passes through the data to filter out potential duplicates.

Comment: What is an acceptable runtime for your use case?

Not sure I understand the comparison of smaller arrays note:

This would only return the same result if you are sure that each array contains items that do not appear in the other arrays.

Comment: I can't get your avatar out of my mind.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Hey Cary, I emailed you a while back for Ruby help. I imagine my avatar sings as a tenor. What do you think?

Comment: [Hmmm](http://www.findingdulcinea.com/docroot/dulcinea/fd_images/features/profiles/p/luciano-pavarotti/features/0/image.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does something like

```
items = 30_000_000

array = items.times.map do
  rand(10_000_000)
end

puts "Done with seeding"
puts
puts "Checking what items appear more than once. Size: #{array.size}"
puts

t1 = Time.now
def more_than_once(array)
  counts = Hash.new(0)
  array.each do |item|
    counts[item] += 1
  end

  counts.select do |_, count|
    count > 1
  end.keys
end

res = more_than_once(array)
t2 = Time.now


p res.size
puts "Took #{t2 - t1}"
```

work for you?

The duration is about 40s on my machine.

Comment: Love the default hash initialization ``counts = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = 0 }``

Comment: You can simplify to `counts = Hash.new(0)`.

Comment: And the counting could be made a one liner using each_with_object:

counts = array.each_with_object(Hash.new) { |item, akku| akku[item] += 1 }

Comment: You forgot `(0)` in `Hash.new(0)` in your last comment.

Comment: Arghh. Thanks, again.

Comment: This works, except for when the size of the data is higher than my RAM at which point this solution quits working :(

Comment: In that case you either need to split the task or use some sort of external storage to store intermediate results.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two more solutions with a benchmark comparison of these and @Pascal's methods.

**Use sets**

```
require 'set'

def multi_set(arr)
  s1 = Set.new
  arr.each_with_object(Set.new) { |e, smulti| smulti.add(e) unless s1.add?(e) }.to_a
end

arr = ["mike", "mike", "mike", "john", "john", "peter", "clark"]    
multi(arr)
  #=> ["mike", "john"]
```

`s1` is being built to include all distinct elements of `arr`. `s1.add?(e)` returns `nil` if `s1` already contains `e`, in which case `e` is added to `smulti` if `smulti` does not already contain that element. (See  [Set#add?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F).) `smulti` is returned by the method.

**Use `Array#difference`**

`Array#difference` is a method I've [proposed](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11815) be added to Ruby's core. See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987054/how-to-select-unique-elements).

```
class Array
  def difference(other)
    h = other.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
    reject { |e| h[e] > 0 && h[e] -= 1 }
  end
end

def multi_difference(arr)
  arr.difference(arr.uniq).uniq
end
```

**Benchmark**

```
def more_than_once(arr)
  counts = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = 0 }
  arr.each do |item|
    counts[item] += 1
  end
  counts.select do |_, count|
    count > 1
  end.keys
end

require 'fruity'

items = 30_000_000
arr = items.times.map { rand 10_000_000 }

compare do 
  Pascal     { more_than_once(arr) }
  Set        { multi_set(arr) }
  Difference { multi_difference(arr) }
end

Running each test once. Test will take about 4 minutes.
Pascal is faster than Set by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
Set is faster than Difference by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0%
```

Of course, `difference`, if part of the Ruby core, would be coded in C and optimized.