# Comparing array elements including duplicates

Tags: arrays, ruby, duplicates, comparison

I am trying to see if an array contains each  element of another array. Plus I want to account for the duplicates. For example:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 3, "abc", "de", "f"]
```

array contains [1, 2, 3, 3] but does not contain [2, 2, "abc"] - too many 2's

I have tried the below but obviously doesn't take into account the dupes.

```
other_arrays.each { |i| array.include? i }
```

Comment: Similarly used the .all? method `other_arrays.all? {|x| array.include? x }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method iterates once over both arrays.
For each array, it creates a hash with the number of occurences of each element.

It then checks that for every unique element in `subset`, there are at least as many elements in `superset`.

```
class Array
  def count_by
    each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e, h| h[e] += 1 }
  end

  def subset_of?(superset)
    superset_counts = superset.count_by
    count_by.all? { |k, count| superset_counts[k] >= count }
  end
end

[1, 2, 3, 3, "abc", "de", "f"].count_by
#=> {1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>2, "abc"=>1, "de"=>1, "f"=>1}

[1, 2, 3, 3].count_by
#=> {1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>2}

[1, 2, 3, 3].subset_of? [1, 2, 3, 3, "abc", "de", "f"]
#=> true
[2, 2, "abc"].subset_of? [1, 2, 3, 3, "abc", "de", "f"]
#=> false
```

If you don't want to patch the `Array` class, you could define :

`count_by(array)` and `subset_of?(array1, array2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could first create a useful instance method for the class `Array`:

```
class Array
  def difference(other)
    h = other.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
    reject { |e| h[e] > 0 && h[e] -= 1 }
  end
end
```

Then all elements of an array `a` are contained in array `b` if the following method returns `true`.

```
def subarray?(a,b)
  a.difference(b).empty?
end
```

For example,

```
subarray? [1,2,3], [1,4,"cat",3,2]
  #=> true
subarray? [1,2,3], [1,4,"cat",3,5]
  #=> false
```

I've found `Array#difference` has such wide application that I [proposed](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11815) that it be added to the Ruby core. Details about the method and its uses can be found at the link and also in my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987054/how-to-select-unique-elements) SO question.