# Fast way to find duplicate in large array

Tags: ruby

I have an array with 35k elements. How may I efficiently find duplicates and return those duplicates?

```
all = [*1..35000, 1]
```

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8922931/517868) works:

```
all.select { |v| all.count(v) > 1 }
```

But it takes a long time.

Comment: _"[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8922931/517868) works: [...] But it takes a long time."_ – did you see the comments / other answers on that page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is taking an eon to execute because it is executing `count` for each element, resulting in it having a *computational complexity* of O(n<sup>2</sup>).

```
arr = [*1..35000, 1, 34999]
```

**If you want to know which values appear in the array at least twice...**

```
require 'set'

uniq_set = Set.new
arr.each_with_object(Set.new) { |x,dup_set| uniq_set.add?(x) || dup_set.add(x) }.to_a
  #=> [1, 34999]
```

Set lookups (implemented with a hash under the covers) are extremely fast.

See [Set#add?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F) and [Set#add](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add).

**If you want to know the numbers of times values appear in the array that appear at least twice...**

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |x,h| h[x] += 1 }.select { |_,v| v > 1 }
  #=> {1=>2, 34999=>2}
```

This uses a *counting hash*<sup>1</sup>. See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) when it takes a *default value* as an argument.

**If you want to know the indices of values that appear in the array at least twice...**

```
arr.each_with_index.
    with_object({}) { |(x,i),h| (h[x] ||= []) << i }.
    select { |_,v| v.size > 1 }
  #=> {1=>[0, 35000], 34999=>[34998, 35001]}
```

When the hash `h` does not already have a key `x`,

```
(h[x] ||= []) << i
   #=> (h[x] = h[x] || []) << i
   #=> (h[x] = nil || []) << i
   #=> (h[x] = []) << i
   #=> [] << i where [] is now h[x]
```

<sup>1. Ruby v2.7 gave us the method [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally), allowing us to write `arr.tally.select { |_,v| v > 1 }`.</sup>

Comment: I was writing something similar. When it comes to uniqueness of elements in a large set, _just use `Set`_.

Answer (score 7):

If you're on Ruby 2.4.0+, you can use `group_by` + [`Hash#transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) (available Ruby 2.4.0):

```
all.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:size).select { |_, freq| freq > 1 }
```

See it in action:

`all.group_by(&:itself)` groups how many times an element appears:

```
{
  1 => [1, 1],
  2 => [2],

  ...

  35000 => [35000]
}
```

Then let's turn the values of above hash into frequency:

`all.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:size)`:

```
{
  1 => 2,
  2 => 1,

  ...

  35000 => 1
}
```

Benchmark:

```
def measure_execution_time
  started = Time.now
  yield
  Time.now - started
end

measure_execution_time do
  all.select { |value| all.count(value) > 1 }
end
=> 7.235489


measure_execution_time do
  all.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:size).select { |_, freq| freq > 1 }
end
=> 0.017887
```

Comment: Damn, that's clever. Minor improvement to match the return value would be to `select { |_, freq| freq > 1 }.keys` to return an array again, instead of a hash.

Comment: The goal here is `[1]` in the output array, so like Brian says, just one step to go and this does it all.

Answer (score 2):

Cary’s solution seems to be the fastest here so far. Here is mine:

```
large_array.sort.each_cons(2).with_object(Set.new) do |(e1, e2), acc|
  acc << e1 if e1 == e2
end.to_a
```

*NB:* unlike Cary’s solution, and like juanitofatas’s one, this might be easily adapted to find those having more than `N` occurrences (just change the parameter to `each_cons`.

Also, if the original array *might be mutated*, this consumes the least amount of memory amongst others (`sort` → `sort!`.)

---

*Benchmarks:*

```
require 'set'
require 'benchmark'

def mudsie arr 
  arr.sort.each_cons(2).each_with_object(Set.new) do |(e1, e2), acc|
    acc << e1 if e1 == e2
  end.to_a
end

def cary arr
  uniq_set = Set.new
  arr.each_with_object(Set.new) do |x,dup_set|
    uniq_set.add?(x) || dup_set.add(x)
  end.to_a
end

def juanitofatas arr 
  arr.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:size).select do |_, freq|
    freq > 1
  end.keys
end

arr = [*(1..35000)]
arr = (arr + arr.sample(500)).shuffle

n = 500

Benchmark.bm do |x| 
  x.report("juanitofatas") { n.times { juanitofatas arr } } 
  x.report("cary") { n.times { cary arr } } 
  x.report("mudsie") { n.times { mudsie arr } } 
end
```

---

```
        user     system      total        real
juanitofatas   4.321030   0.000000    4.321030 (  4.321232)
        cary   3.229409   0.032003    3.261412 (  3.261995)
      mudsie   3.798093   0.000000    3.798093 (  3.798141)
```

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark, mudsie. They're all pretty close, so close that any might rise to the top with different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just count them yourself?

```
counter = Hash.new(0)
array.each { |e| counter[e] += 1 }
counter.select! { |k, v| v > 1 }
counter.keys

# OR

array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e, h| h[e] += 1 }
     .select! { |k, v| v > 1 }
     .keys
```

It has O(n) complexity and I don't think you can go faster than that (I mean faster than O(n))

Comment: Typo here: `counter.select! { |k, v| > 1 }` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Great replies!

My version inspired by [Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland) but more verbose, just one line less than [Nondv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3891844/nondv) with `select` instead of `select!`, which seems even faster:

```
def igian(arr)
  h = Hash.new(0)
  arr.each { |a| h[a] += 1 }
  h.select { |_k, v| v > 1 }
end
```

**Benchmark on all replies**, inspired by [mudasobwa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035262/mudasobwa).

```
n = 500
         user     system      total        real
cary1    5.040000   0.200000   5.240000 (  5.248103)
cary2    4.700000   0.190000   4.890000 (  4.911883)
juanito  7.430000   0.030000   7.460000 (  7.483123)
mudsie   5.430000   0.020000   5.450000 (  5.460839)
nondv1   4.720000   0.190000   4.910000 (  4.924792)
nondv2   5.110000   0.190000   5.300000 (  5.317148)
igian    4.310000   0.190000   4.500000 (  4.522211)
```

---

```
n = 1000
         user     system      total        real
cary1   10.460000   0.410000  10.870000 ( 10.900927)
cary2    9.550000   0.410000   9.960000 (  9.989021)
juanito 15.370000   0.160000  15.530000 ( 15.569288)
mudsie  10.920000   0.020000  10.940000 ( 10.972357)
nondv1   9.590000   0.410000  10.000000 ( 10.017669)
nondv2  10.340000   0.410000  10.750000 ( 10.774538)
igian    8.790000   0.400000   9.190000 (  9.213292)
```

**Here is the benchmark code:**

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'set'

arr = [*1..35000, 1]

def cary1(arr)
  uniq_set = Set.new
  arr.each_with_object(Set.new) { |x,dup_set| uniq_set.add?(x) || dup_set.add(x) }.to_a
end

def cary2(arr)
  arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |x,h| h[x] += 1 }.select { |_,v| v > 1 }
end

def juanito(arr)
  arr.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:size).select { |_,v| v > 1 }
end

def mudsie(arr)
  arr.sort.each_cons(2).each_with_object(Set.new) do |(e1, e2), acc|
    acc << e1 if e1 == e2
  end.to_a
end

def nondv1(arr)
  counter = Hash.new(0)
  arr.each { |e| counter[e] += 1 }
  counter.select! { |k, v| v > 1 }
  counter.keys
end

def nondv2(arr)
  arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e, h| h[e] += 1 }
     .select! { |k, v| v > 1 }
     .keys
end

def igian(arr)
  h = Hash.new(0)
  arr.each { |a| h[a] += 1 }
  h.select { |_k, v| v > 1 }
end

n = 500 #1000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("cary1") { n.times { cary1 arr } }
  x.report("cary2") { n.times { cary2 arr } }
  x.report("juanito") { n.times { juanito arr } }
  x.report("mudsie") { n.times { mudsie arr } }
  x.report("nondv1") { n.times { nondv1 arr } }
  x.report("nondv2") { n.times { nondv2 arr } }
  x.report("igian") { n.times { igian arr } }
end
```

Comment: It’s funny that `select` is faster than `select!`.

Comment: Some of these methods output a list of values that occur in duplicate, while some output a hash with the values as keys and a count. I added .keys to those to compare apples to apples and got similar benchmarks, but there's only one dupe in these tests. So I changed the array to `arr = [*1..35000, *1..10000]` Interestingly, nondv1 was the top performer for me in the case of many duplicates, and it had little to do with the .keys conversion.