# How to find duplicate array of hash and print them in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have array of hash :

```
[
  {:name=>"King Summer", :number=>"0034242342"}, 
  {:name=>"Max Snow", :number=>"899899080"}, 
  {:name=>"Duck Doe", :number=>"90897688"}, 
  {:name=>"Shark Jon", :number=>"0034242342"}
]
```

At the above, the value of key `:number` `{:name=>"King Summer", :number=>"0034242342"}` duplicated with `{:name=>"Shark Jon", :number=>"0034242342"}`

How to find the duplicate *:number* and showing output like this in console :

```
=== List with duplicate number ===
King Summer – 0034242342 : ok
Max Snow – 899899080 : ok
Duck Doe – 90897688 : ok
Shark Jon – 0034242342 : duplicate number

== List without duplicate number ===
1 - King Summer – 0034242342
2 - Max Snow – 899899080
3 - Duck Doe – 90897688
```

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby: How to find and return a duplicate value in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921999/ruby-how-to-find-and-return-a-duplicate-value-in-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add status using `inject` where inject's accumulator will hold numbers passed in previous iterations,

```
arr.inject([]) { |m,a| m.include?(a[:number]) ? (a[:status] = 'duplicated number') : ((m << a[:number]) && (a[:status] = 'ok')); m} 

arr
# [
#  {:name=>"King Summer", :number=>"0034242342", :status=>"ok"}, 
#  {:name=>"Max Snow", :number=>"899899080", :status=>"ok"}, 
#  {:name=>"Duck Doe", :number=>"90897688", :status=>"ok"}, 
#  {:name=>"Shark Jon", :number=>"0034242342", :status=>"duplicated number"}
# ]
```

Iterate your this data using `each` later.

Comment: Thank you, but `duplicated number` status not added, all statu s`ok`. I've try in irb:

irb(main):011:0> arr.inject([]) { |m,a| a.include?(a[:number]) ? (a[:status] = 'duplicated number') : ((m << a[:number]) && (a[:status] = 'ok')); m}
=> ["0034242342", "899899080", "90897688", "0034242342"]

irb(main):012:0> arr
=> [{:name=>"King Summer", :number=>"0034242342", :status=>"ok"}, {:name=>"Max Snow", :number=>"899899080", :status=>"ok"}, {:name=>"Duck Doe", :number=>"90897688", :status=>"ok"}, {:name=>"Shark Jon", :number=>"0034242342", :status=>"ok"}]

Comment: @spn Sorry there was minor correction as `m.include?` was needed instead of `a.include?`. Please check updated answer

Comment: Thanks! Note that existing array is updated here, accept if it work around for you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way. Maybe not the cleanest way.

```
duplicated = []
non_duplicated = []

array = [
  {:name=>"King Summer", :number=>"0034242342"}, 
  {:name=>"Max Snow", :number=>"899899080"}, 
  {:name=>"Duck Doe", :number=>"90897688"}, 
  {:name=>"Shark Jon", :number=>"0034242342"}
]

array.each do |a| 

  is_duplicated = non_duplicated.find do |i|
    i == a[:number]
  end

  if is_duplicated
    duplicated.push(a[:number])
    non_duplicated.delete(a[:number])
    next
  end

  non_duplicated.push(a[:number])

end
```

### Edit

Alternative

```
array.partition do |value|
  number = value[:number]

  array.map do |i|
    i[:number]
  end.count(number) > 1
end
```

This will return an array with 2 parts (duplicated, and the rest) :

```
[
  [
    {:name=>"King Summer", :number=>"0034242342"}, 
    {:name=>"Shark Jon", :number=>"0034242342"}
  ], 
  [
    {:name=>"Max Snow", :number=>"899899080"},
    {:name=>"Duck Doe", :number=>"90897688"}
  ]
]
```

Comment: Better to use [`partition`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/partition) if you're assigning to two arrays in this manner :)

Comment: @SRack thank you for your feedback :), i didnt know this way. I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Other option is building a hash which groups duplicated (true) and not (false).

Given the array:

```
ary = [
        {name: "King Summer", number: "0034242342"}, 
        {name: "Max Snow", number: "899899080"}, 
        {name: "Duck Doe", number: "90897688"}, 
        {name: "Shark Jon", number: "0034242342"},
        {name: "Jim Kirk", number: "90897688"},
        {name: "Mr. Spock", number: "10897688"}
      ]
```

Build the hash:

```
res = ary.group_by { |h| h[:number] }.group_by { |_,v| v.size > 1 }.transform_values(&:to_h)

#=> {true=>{"0034242342"=>[{:name=>"King Summer", :number=>"0034242342"}, {:name=>"Shark Jon", :number=>"0034242342"}], "90897688"=>[{:name=>"Duck Doe", :number=>"90897688"}, {:name=>"Jim Kirk", :number=>"90897688"}]}, false=>{"899899080"=>[{:name=>"Max Snow", :number=>"899899080"}], "10897688"=>[{:name=>"Mr. Spock", :number=>"10897688"}]}}
```

Then list the duplicated:

```
res[true].each do |number, people|
  puts "- ph. number: #{number}"
  people.each { |person| puts "\t"*2 + person[:name] }
end

# - ph. number: 0034242342
#     King Summer
#     Shark Jon
# - ph. number: 90897688
#     Duck Doe
#     Jim Kirk
```

---

Or

```
res.each do |_, list|
  puts "-"*10
  list.each do |number, people|
    puts "- ph. number: #{number}"
    people.each { |person| puts "\t"*2 + person[:name] }
  end
end

# ----------
# - ph. number: 0034242342
#     King Summer
#     Shark Jon
# - ph. number: 90897688
#     Duck Doe
#     Jim Kirk
# ----------
# - ph. number: 899899080
#     Max Snow
# - ph. number: 10897688
#     Mr. Spock
```