# How to query to return the most common foreign key in a join table with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I have 3 models. Project, ProjectMaterial, and Material

A Project has_many ProjectMaterials and many Materials through ProjectMaterials.

This is bidirectional, with ProjectMaterial acting as a join table with user-submittable attributes.

I'd like to query the ProjectMaterial model to find the most frequent value of material_id. This way I can use it to find the most frequently used material.

Any help with a query would be greatly appreciated. I'm stuck. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way could be pluck ids to get the array, then count the most frequent.

```
ids = ProjectMaterial.pluck[:material_id]
```

For example: [Ruby: How to find item in array which has the most occurrences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412169/ruby-how-to-find-item-in-array-which-has-the-most-occurrences)

Or better, by query to get a hash with counts:

```
counts = ProjectMaterial.group(:material_id).count
```

Once you know that you get a hash, you can sort by any ruby method, picking the most frequent or the n most frequent. Example of sorting:

```
counts.sort_by { |_, v| v }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain `group`, `count` and `sort` methods on your ActiveRecord query like this:

```
ProjectMaterial.group(:material_id).count.values.sort.last
```

The first part `ProjectMaterial.group(:material_id).count` gives you the hash of each `{material_id0 => rows_count0, material_id1 => rows_count1, ...}`. Then, you can just get the values of the hash in an array, sort it and get the last item.