# Find N number of common attributes in an array of structs

Tags: ruby

I have the following struct:

```
Name = Struct.new(:first_name, :last_name) do
  def greeting
    "Hello #{first_name}!"
  end
end
```

I am adding these objects to an array like this:

```
full_names << Name.new(first_name, last_name)
```

Now, I'd like to find the N most common first names.

Comment: I feel something like `full_names.uniq.map(&:first_name) { |n| full_names.count(n) }.max` is a first step, but that gives me a block/arg error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was a solution I came up with based on Sophie's answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412169/ruby-how-to-find-item-in-array-which-has-the-most-occurrences/7782599).

First, this gives me a hash of first names and the number of occurrences of each:

```
freq_of_first_names = full_names.map(&:first_name).inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
 => "Haley"=>122, "Auer"=>119, "Lakin"=>96, "Macejkovic"=>98...
```

Now I can sort this with the `.sort_by` method, and also adding the `.last` method along with the number of records I want returned (in this case 10).

```
freq_of_first_names.sort_by {|_key, value| value}.last(10)
```

Comment: As an aside `max_by(10, &:last)` can replace `.sort_by {|_key, value| value}.last(10)`. Enumerable#max_by takes accepts an argument for the maximum number of results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to create a hash mapping each first name to an array of all of its occurrences in the array, [`transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) to turn each value array of strings into a count, then [`max_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) to extract the largest `n` counts.

```
Name = Struct.new(:first_name, :last_name) do
  def greeting
    "Hello #{first_name}!"
  end
end

full_names = [
  Name.new("a", "b"),
  Name.new("b", "c"),
  Name.new("d", "c"),
  Name.new("c", "d"),
  Name.new("d", "c"),
  Name.new("b", "b"),
  Name.new("b", "e")
]
n = 2

p full_names
  .group_by(&:first_name)
  .transform_values(&:size)
  .max_by(n, &:last)
```

Output:

```
[["b", 3], ["d", 2]]
```

If you only want the first names and not the counts, append `.map(&:first)` to the chain.

Comment: Nice work ggorlen! I'm adding a solution I came up with in the meantime below.

Comment: I personally don't like the `[0...n]` syntax after a block and would rather do `.first(n)` or `.take(n)` the line below, this is just personal preference though.

Comment: Yeah, that's certainly valid. Without doubt `.first` is more semantically meaningful. I'm coming from Python where slices are pretty much everywhere, so seeing the `[]`s tends to click more instantly for me than parsing an English word in my brain, but I think your suggestion is more idiomatic in Ruby.

Comment: As an aside `max_by(n, &:last)` can replace `.sort_by{|k, v| -v}.first(n)` in the first example. `Enumerable#max_by` takes accepts an argument for the maximum number of results.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks--whenever I answer a Ruby question, there's always some better function folks tell me about!

Answer (score 1):

```
full_names = [
  Name.new("Bob", "Feller"),
  Name.new("Hank", "Jones"),
  Name.new("Annie", "Oakley"),
  Name.new("Cher", ""),
  Name.new("Annie", "Hall"),
  Name.new("Melba", "Toast"),
  Name.new("Bob", "Dylan"),
  Name.new("Hank", "Wiliams"),
  Name.new("Bob", "Marley")
]
```

```
nbr_most_common = 3
```

```
full_names.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |i,h| h[i[:first_name]] += 1 }.
           max_by(nbr_most_common, &:last).
           map(&:first)
  #=> ["Bob", "Hank", "Annie"]
```

If you wish to also display the frequency, change the last line to `to_h`:

```
full_names.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |i,h| h[i[:first_name]] += 1 }.
           max_by(nbr_most_common, &:last).
           to_h
   #=> {"Bob"=>3, "Hank"=>2, "Annie"=>2}
```

See the version of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-c-new) that creates a *default value* (here zero) and [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-c-new).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0.preview1/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) in 2.7

```rb
Name = Struct.new(:first_name, :last_name) do
  def greeting
    "Hello #{first_name}!"
  end
end

full_names = [
  Name.new("Yui", "Yoko"),
  Name.new("Bob", "Feller"),
  Name.new("Hank", "Jones"),
  Name.new("Annie", "Oakley"),
  Name.new("Cher", ""),
  Name.new("Annie", "Hall"),
  Name.new("Melba", "Toast"),
  Name.new("Bob", "Dylan"),
  Name.new("Hank", "Wiliams"),
  Name.new("Bob", "Marley")
]

full_names.map(&:first_name).tally.max_by(3, &:last) 
#=> [["Bob", 3], ["Annie", 2], ["Hank", 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same example:

```rb
Name = Struct.new(:first_name, :last_name) do
  def greeting
    "Hello #{first_name}!"
  end
end

full_names = [
  Name.new("a", "b"),
  Name.new("b", "c"),
  Name.new("d", "c"),
  Name.new("c", "d"),
  Name.new("d", "c"),
  Name.new("b", "b"),
  Name.new("b", "e")
]
```

We can use `inject` to create a Hash with `first_name => frequency`:

```rb
first_names = full_names.map(&:first_name)
first_names #["a", "b", "d", "c", "d", "b", "b"]
hash_of_frequency = first_names.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
hash_of_frequency # [["b", 3], ["d", 2], ["a", 1], ["c", 1]]
```

Now we just execute a `sort_by` and get your results:

```rb
hash_of_frequency.sort_by{|k, v| -v}.first(number_desired)
```

The result is the same, but I've preferred to use `inject`